# About a $p$-th power residue

Tags: elementary-number-theory

A sentence I was reading reads "Let $p$ be a prime factor of $n$. Take another prime $l$ with $l\equiv1\pmod{2p}$ so that $-1$ is a $p$-th power residue mod $l$."

Was it saying that for any prime $l$ satisfying $l\equiv1\pmod{2p}$, $-1$ is a $p$-th power residue mod $l$? Or was it saying to take a prime $l$ such that both (1) $l\equiv1\pmod{2p}$ and (2) $-1$ is a $p$-th power residue mod $l$ hold?

Comment: If $p$ is odd then $(-1) = (-1)^p$, so the hypothesis of $-1$ being a $p$th power residue automatically holds in a simple way; it has no nontrivial content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $l$ is odd and $r$ is a primitive root modulo $l$, then 
$r^{l-1}\equiv 1 \pmod{l} $.  So if $x = r^{(l-1)/2},$ we have $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{l}.$  The only solutions are $x\equiv \pm 1\ pmod{l}$, but since $r$ is a primitive root, we must have $x\equiv -1 \pmod{l}.$

Now note that $l\equiv 1 \pmod{2p}$ means that $l-1 = 2pd$ for some $d,$ which can be written $(l-1)/2 =pd.$  Then you have

$$-1 \equiv x \equiv r^{(l-1)/2} \equiv r^{pd} \equiv (r^d)^p \pmod{l}, $$

showing that your first condition implies the second.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is easy to understand.